# I won the dv lottery but will my past uk removal affect my application?

Tags: usa, visa, overstay, asylum

I'm a USA diversity visa (dv) lottery winner. I have some past mistakes. I overstayed in UK for more than 2 years after my case was refused by the home office. They found me and had me removed from the UK.

Now I'm worried that this mistake will affect my dv application? I'm from Nepal. I applied for UK pcc (police clearance certificate) that I'm waiting for as well. If anyone has any experience,  please share with me.

Comment: What do you mean by your "case" that was refused?

Comment: I climb the asylum case that was refused

Answer (score 2):

It might affect, it might not, but you will not gain anything by waiting. You need to apply, disclose everything they ask (but do not volunteer anything).

If you have resources, consider hiring a good immigration lawyer. https://www.shusterman.com/ is top US immigration lawyer firm, and has huge amount of info on their website.

Also, you need to hurry. Every year they issue more DV visas, assuming that not all winner will apply, so they can run out of slots.